# How to Access Tabulator Columns for Formatting from a return by ajax:Response

Tags: tabulator

After getting my first working example using a web service call to work with Tabulator, I now face another issue with accessing the data from the ajaxResponse returned response. How do I set up columns specific to the response returned by the AJAX (Tabulator) call?  I have tried the raw column names as they exist in the JSON object array to no avail.  The list displays blank rows.  If I set "autoColumns:true" as a property, I see the data expected, just not in the format nor the # of columns I need to display to the user.  Below is the code.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Ben

```
var usernameval = '*****';
var passwordval = '*****';
var urlHIBRS = 'http://vm-win10-05:8080/Hibrs/hibrs/nibrs/getLatestNibrsHeaders';

var ajaxConfigHIBRS = {
    dataType:'json',
    data:{},
    credentials: 'include',

    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json', //tell the server we need JSON back
        'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest', //fix to help some frameworks respond correctly to request
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8', //set specific content type        
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(usernameval + ':' + passwordval),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://192.168.0.65', //the URL origin of the site making the request
    },
};

var table = new Tabulator('#example-table', {
    ajaxConfig:ajaxConfigHIBRS,
    ajaxURL:urlHIBRS,

    pagination:'local',
    paginationSize:100,
    paginationDataSent:{
        'page':'pageNumber',
        'size':'pageSize',
    },
/* Paging issues
    paginationDataReceived:{
        'last_page':'totalPages',
    },
*/    

    layout:'fitColumns',
    autoColumns:true,
    height:'100%',
    placeholder:'No Data Set',
    selectable:1,

    /*
    columns:[   // define the table columns
        {title:"Type", field:"response.reporttype"},
        {title:"Report No.", field:"reportno"},
        {title:"Version", field:"versionnumber"},
        {title:"Period", field:"submissionperiod"},
        {title:"State Status", field:"statesubmissionstatus"},
        {title:"FBI Status", field:"fbisubmissionstatus"},
        {title:"Last Submitted", field:"lastsubmittedon", sorter:"date"},
    ],
    */

    ajaxRequesting:function(url, params) {
        //alert('url = ' + url);
        //url - the URL of the requestac
        //params - the parameters passed with the request
    },

    ajaxResponse:function(url, params, response) {
        return response.list;  
    },
    ajaxError:function(error){
        //error - the returned error object
        alert('error = ' + error);
    },    

});
```

Comment: it is likely that you are not passing your data to Tabulator in a format it is expecting. it would be helpful if you could include a snippet of your ajax response in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this myself. The backend developer was sending different field names than what I was expecting. Once I aligned the names, all is well.